# vcovHC (heteroskedasticity) in pooled and panel probit

Tags: panel-data, probit

I run two types of regressions in R:

1) Using a panel probit of the following form
    `glm_panel <- pglm(formula=Formula,data=Regress_Sample,na.action=na.exclude,family=binomial(probit),index=c("ID","Date")))`

2) A pooled probit of the follwing form
    `glm_pooled <- glm(formula=Formula,data=Regress_Sample,na.action=na.exclude,family=binomial(probit)))`

I then computed my standard errors in order to account for potential heteroskedasticity in my `Regress_Sample`

`coeftest(glm_pooled, function(x) vcovHC(x, method="arellano",type="HC1"))`

It works perfecly with the pooled probit however with the panel probit I get

`Error in terms.default(object) : no terms component nor attribute`

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it seems like the documentation for `pglm` is incorrect, and the function does not work as advertised.

The error message is quite simply because the generic function `terms` does not know how to extract terms in a format it understands from the result of `pglm`; it results to the default method (`terms.default`) before failing there.

The return object of `pglm` is **NOT** of class `pglm` (which is what is suggested in `?pglm`), and does not contain all of the components listed therein (typically a regression object, e.g. from `lm`, returns a `terms` component)

Following the example in `?pglm`:

```
data('Fairness', package = 'pglm')
Parking <- subset(Fairness, good == 'parking')
op <- pglm(as.numeric(answer) ~ education + rule,
           Parking[1:105, ],
           family = ordinal('probit'), R = 5, print.level = 3,
           method = 'bfgs', index = 'id',  model = "random")
class(op)
# [1] "maxLik" "maxim"
names(op)
#  [1] "maximum"     "estimate"    "gradient"    "hessian"     "code"       
#  [6] "message"     "last.step"   "fixed"       "iterations"  "type"       
# [11] "constraints" "gradientObs" "control"     "call"        "args"       
# [16] "model"
```

This directly contradicts the documentation:

> Value: An object of class "pglm", a list with elements...

Several of the listed elements are indeed found here, but not all. I've written the package maintainer.